# Proving that $P($$\{\text{$a$ and $b$ are co-prime}$ }$)=0$ for $a,b$ following the Uniform distribution over $[n, 2n]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, limit-theorems, formal-proof

I have been working on a problem concerning the "line of sight" from a fixed integer co-ordinate — let's say $(0,0)$ — to a variable co-ordinate $(a,b)$. Having a line of sight means that there are no other integer co-ordinates on a straight line connecting the two points.

This is a a well documented problem and there isn't very much that's worth exploring on it. However, when investigating the long run behaviour, I noticed that if were look at the probability that a uniformly chosen point has a line of sight as the co-ordinate approaches infinity (I define this more formally below), then the proof that this probability approaches $0$ relies on the fact that the probability that these the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates are co-prime also approaches $0$. This is a fact that is clearly true (at least intuitively), however, I have struggled to construct (or find) a proof of this fact.

More formally, my question asks the following:

> Prove that for $a,b \sim \operatorname{Uniform}\{n, \space n+1, \dotsc \space 2n\}$, the following is true:
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(\{ \text{$a$ and $b$ are co-prime} \}) \rightarrow0$$
> as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

As stated above, this is clearly true. What I am after is either a proof or a reference to a proof of the above claim so that I can justify this result rigorously.

I would be grateful for any contributions here.

---

Note: as discussed in the comments, I am aware of the fact that for any two randomly chosen positive integers, the probability that they are coprime will be $6 / \pi^2$ [(see proof here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2), however, the application of this to my question is not immediately clear me to beyond providing me with the intuition for my conjecture.

Comment: I believe the probability they’re coprime converges to $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I interpreted the opposite of what the question asks (that the prob that they are not coprime is $0$). I will delete my previous comment

Comment: It is still $6/\pi^2$ for sure. Points with coprime coordinates are equidistributed on the plane with this density.

Comment: Infinite probability, how? Probabilities do not add up, you take a weighted average if them.

Comment: @FD_bfa actually for any rectangle $\Delta_1\times \Delta_2$ with both sides tending to infinity the proportion is close to $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: Joe's argument works, for example.

Comment: For what it’s worth I have a paper calculating something like this in a strip with irrational slope and finite height. The conclusion there is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to get the probability is still the usual $1/\zeta(2)$ by the usual inclusion/exclusion argument, but possibly there's a mistake in the following calculation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{a,b\in[n,2n]} \;\;\sum_{d\mid(a,b)} \mu(d)
&= \frac{1}{n^2}
\sum_{1\le d\le 2n} \mu(d)\sum_{\substack{A,B\\ A\in[n/d,2n/d]
\\ B\in[n/d,2n/d] \\}} 1 \quad\text{setting $a=Ad$ and $b=Bd$,}\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\mu(d) \sum_{1\le d\le 2n} \left(\frac{n}{d} + O(1)\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{1\le d\le 2n} \mu(d)\frac{n^2}{d^2} + O\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) \\
&= \sum_{1\le d\le 2n} \mu(d)\frac{1}{d^2}
+ O\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1\le d\le 2n}\frac{1}{d}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} +  O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Your answer suggests that the probability as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is non-zero. However, if the limit is positive, then by taking disjoint "rings" that add up to the whole ball don't you end up with infinite probability for the limit over the whole ball? (as the logical extension from this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2 which deals with the probability for a completely random pairing of $a,b$) - where my question asks specifically for the probability along the "edge" of the ball as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @FD_bfa, Joe is computing the probability that a random pair $a,b$ sampled uniformly from the interval $\{n,\ldots,2n\}$ is coprime (see his first left-hand side). Intuitively, the answer to your question should be very similar to the answer for the initial segment $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by standard dyadic decomposition manipulations. The reason your first comment does not hold is that you have not renormalized the sum over rings, i.e. you need to divide by the number of rings you used to add up.

Comment: Perhaps a question that would be better suited to distinguish from the initial segment $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ would be to consider short intervals of the form $\{n,\ldots,n+n^\varepsilon\}$ (say with $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$). This looks a bit more like the "edge" of a ball than the ball itself. @FD_bfa